# Where is hibernate configuration class in hibernate-core

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

i'm trying to use hibernate in a maven project . So i include these dependancies in my projet which are supposed to be enough as i read. I have access to the jakarta package so i successfuly mapped my classes but now i'm trying to insert a row in database to test and understand how it works. But when i try to find a tutorial which explain how i can do they all use a class org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration to read an xml file but i don't have this class in my project i suppose it was a part of previous versions but now how i can do ?? or am i the one which doesn't understand ??

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.33</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.2.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
```